# Not able to give scrollbar

Tags: android, scrollview

How to add scrolling feature to this layout please help

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/expanded_thumbnail"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sangam 2015"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/expanded_title"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8-10th September 2015"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/expanded_date"
            android:layout_below="@+id/expanded_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/expanded_title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/expanded_title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="My name is dushyant suthar"
            android:id="@+id/expanded_description"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/expanded_date"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/expanded_date"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/expanded_date" />

    </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

When I am using the above code the ImageView is getting small (the height of image is getting decreased) and noting like scrolling in The whole layout.

I dont know about Scroll views I did not understand by googling I want a good link and also solution of above XML and what should I add in Java code

Answer (score 0):

your code seems ok to me but try by removing android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout import or android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"